# Пропадает перевод для описания причины закрытия "Вопрос слишком общий"

Tags: дефект, локализация

Несколько раз замечал, что в очереди проверки пропадает перевод для причин закрытия, вот например для "Вопрос слишком общий":

[image: Вопрос слишком общий]

Сегодня также попадался пропавший перевод для описания какой-то причины закрытия из группы "Не по теме", но сейчас уже не вспомню для какой.

Comment: @alexolut, да похоже на то

Comment: В таком случае можете подтвердить кнопкой. А ещё у Вас кажется очепятка в профиле: "Прогаммист".

Comment: @alexolut, да, спасибо, поправил.